# Web application using SpringMVC /JQuery

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, gwt

I am analyzing java web frameworks for web application, the web application will basically communicate to rmi to retrieve the data and render the contents in GUI(no major business processing is needed only rendering of the data objects in presentation layer is required), So back end application will only sending/receiving data to rmi from GUI(maximum users of the application may not be greater than 10-20). As there can be data like one million entries in grid so the main requirement is performance of the application should be good. Also the other requirement is user friendly and responsive GUI.

I have analyzed few frameworks like Spring MVC, GWT, Vaadin and ZK, they all have few advantages and disadvantages of it, After analysis i have selected Spring MVC+ J Query for the web application framework but i have few queries in the same

1. Is there any constraint related to performance using spring MVC?
2. How difficult is to learn J Query for developers coming from java desktop based application background?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **Is it a good idea to use framework like spring core/spring MVC for

  business logic and GWT or ZK as presentation layer? Will this deliver
  good performance?**

Spring MVC is definitely a good idea to use as your Web framework. It offers vast variety of features at multiple levels (Business, Database, Web). I have a very minimal exp with GWT and none with ZK. However for presentation layer I would recommend HTML/JSP with AngularJS. We are using it for couple of projects and have found it highly efficient and easy.

- **Is it better to use spring core instead of Spring MVC as it is light
  weight compare to spring MVC.**

Spring Core is a standalone framework for pure Java apps. If you use Spring MVC you are also using Spring Core. So if you are going for web app, then better use Spring MVC

- **Is there any other good server centric/client centric framework
  better than above?**

There are others as well. There is pure JS based frameworks like Node/Express/Meteor. There is Struts/Grails/JBoss Seam/JSF etc which are Java based. Have a look at this [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_application_frameworks#Java).

- **Please suggest me what would be the preferable technology stack to
  develop the application.**

IMHO my suggestion would be Java/SpringMVC/AngularJS/JSP because I have been using it for some time now  and haven't found any major issues.

Comment: thanks for the response,one query between Grails and Spring which one is preferable, I have read that spring MVC can cause performance problem for small/Medium size web application due to large no. of spring jars is this correct? we want to achieve Rich UI(having wizards, menus,tables,trees etc.) and also the team i have has no experience in html/css so just thinking whether to choose java based UI framework(GWT,Vaadin). Is Spring MVC+ JQuery is sufficient one for displaying rich controls as well good performance?